# PHP Xdebug with NetBeans and Apache

Tags: php, netbeans, apache2, xdebug

I’m trying to do my first steps with PHP. I decided to use NetBeans, which seams helpful.

NetBeans is running on my local Windows machine. My testpage is running on an Apache2 webserver in my Ubuntu HyperV M.

Up to now everything works fine. Now I enabled remote debugging over Xdebug. Therefore I added the following lines to the php.ini:

```
[debug]
; Remote settings
xdebug.remote_autostart=off
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.2.20
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

The connection is ok and debugging works. Unfortunately the debugger stops at each line and not only at my breakpoints. That makes my tests inefficient. Therefore my question is how to tell NetBeans to stop at breakpoints only?

Comment: You probably need [path mapping](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/path-mapping-in-php-debugger).

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution by myself. There is an option "stop at first line" in the Netbeans PHP debugging settings. Removing that did the trick.